# (RSA) This script I got off of stackoverflow returns a negative d value

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa

So I stumbled upon this thread on here with this script and it returns a negative d value and my p and q values are both prime. Any reason for this? Possibly just a faulty script?

```
def egcd(a, b):
    x,y, u,v = 0,1, 1,0
    while a != 0:
        q, r = b//a, b%a
        m, n = x-u*q, y-v*q
        b,a, x,y, u,v = a,r, u,v, m,n
        gcd = b
    return gcd, x, y

def main():

    p = 153143042272527868798412612417204434156935146874282990942386694020462861918068684561281763577034706600608387699148071015194725533394126069826857182428660427818277378724977554365910231524827258160904493774748749088477328204812171935987088715261127321911849092207070653272176072509933245978935455542420691737433
    q = 156408916769576372285319235535320446340733908943564048157238512311891352879208957302116527435165097143521156600690562005797819820759620198602417583539668686152735534648541252847927334505648478214810780526425005943955838623325525300844493280040860604499838598837599791480284496210333200247148213274376422459183
    e = 65537
    ct = 313988037963374298820978547334691775209030794488153797919908078268748481143989264914905339615142922814128844328634563572589348152033399603422391976806881268233227257794938078078328711322137471700521343697410517378556947578179313088971194144321604618116160929667545497531855177496472117286033893354292910116962836092382600437895778451279347150269487601855438439995904578842465409043702035314087803621608887259671021452664437398875243519136039772309162874333619819693154364159330510837267059503793075233800618970190874388025990206963764588045741047395830966876247164745591863323438401959588889139372816750244127256609

    # compute n
    n = p * q

    # Compute phi(n)
    phi = (p - 1) * (q - 1)

    # Compute modular inverse of e
    gcd, a, b = egcd(e, phi)
    d = a

    print( "n:  " + str(d) );

    # Decrypt ciphertext
    pt = pow(ct,d,n)
    print( "pt: " + str(pt) )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen, I'll explain why below, but for practical purposes you'll want to know how to fix it.  The answer to that is to add `phi` to `d` and use that value instead: everything will work as RSA should.

So why does it happen?  The algorithm computes the extended gcd.  The result of egcd is `a*e + b*phi = gcd`, and in the case of RSA, we have `gcd = 1` so `a*e + b*phi = 1`.

If you look at this equation modulo `phi` (which is the order of the multiplicative group), then `a*e == 1 mod phi` which is what you need to make RSA work.  In fact, by the same congruence, you can add or subtract any multiple of `phi` to `a` and the congruence still holds.

Now look at the equation again: `a*e + b*phi = 1`.  We know `e` and `phi` are positive integers.  You can't have all positive integers in this equation or else no way would it add up to 1 (it would be much larger than 1).  So that means either `a` or `b` is going to be negative.  Sometimes it will be `a` that is negative, other times it will be `b`.  When it is `b`, then your `a` comes out as you would expect: a positive integer that you then assign to the value `d`.  But the other times, you get a negative value for `a`.  We don't want that, so simply add `phi` to it and make that your value of `d`.